# Ratchet WebSocket won't work over Vagrant machine

Tags: php, sockets, vagrant, ratchet

I have a WebSocket server using [Ratchet](https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet) (literally the example app). I'm serving it to `localhost:8080` on my Vagrant machine (which is a CentOS 6) and trying to connect to it through the private network IP set in the Vagrantfile `192.168.33.10`.

I'm getting a `connect ECONNREFUSED 192.168.33.10:8080` (the uri is `ws://192.168.33.10:8080/chat`).

I already exposed the port `config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8080`.

I've tried serving the server (inside vagrant) to `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` and `192.168.33.10`, but the client still can't connect.

It works fine outside of Vagrant using `localhost` on both client and server.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you bind the app to `localhost` there is no way you can access it via `192.168.33.10`, hence port forwarding won't work either.

You need to make your app to listen on `192.168.33.10:8080`.

Also add the guest's IP address to the Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest_ip: "192.168.33.10", guest: 8080, host: 8080
```

Comment: Tried this, still doesn't work. I'm binding the socket server inside the vagrant machine, and it's listening to `192.168.33.10:8080`,  then the client on my host machine is trying to connect to that same address. Did I do something?

Comment: Oh wait, this worked, the problem was that I was passing the hostname but not the IP to Ratchet. Thanks